# oracle 10g , query format

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a small doubt. I have below query

```
SELECT empno 
        || '|' 
        || ename 
        || '|' 
        || sal 
        || '|' 
        || comm 
FROM   (SELECT empno, 
               ename, 
               sal, 
               comm 
        FROM   emp);
```

the output is coming as :

```
7611|Grp Fract|2001|.11
7499|ALLEN WOR|1600|.22
7521|WARD|1250|10.23
7566|JONES|2975|234.23
7654|MARTIN|1250|.98
```

the last column COMM has value as 0.11, 0.22, 0.98

but the above query returns data as .11,.22,.98. Can anyone help me understanding why it is happening when I am concatenating the data and how to resolve this , I need exact value as it is in COMM column.

The o/p should be as

```
7611|Grp Fract|2001|0.11
7499|ALLEN WOR|1600|0.22
7521|WARD|1250|10.23
7566|JONES|2975|234.23
7654|MARTIN|1250|0.98
```

Ths comm column is defined as `number(7,2)`.

Thanks

Comment: "I need exact value as it is in COMM column": in the COMM column it is merely a number, it is not formatted for display.

Comment: Why would you even do that? What's wrong with the much more readable `SELECT empno || '|' || ename || '|' || sal || '|' || comm FROM emp;`?

In other words, why the subquery?

Answer (score 7):

Use the `TO_CHAR` function with a [proper format model](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements004.htm#i34510). It seems you want `LTRIM(TO_CHAR(comm,'999990.99'))` here.

Comment: @Benoit: just curious - how to get link to a proper oracle version documentation fast? Google always refers to 9, 10, 11, 11.1, not the latest 11.2. Is there any secret? ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: I don't know, but I came there using [Duckduckgo](http://ddg.gg) with the `!oracle` bang syntax.

Comment: Hi Benoit, thanks for the reply, but when i add LTRIM(TO_CHAR(comm,'999990.99')) , it is giving me 10.00 as well, I need the number as it is , it should be 10. Also , can you please explain me why you kept 0 in '9999990'.

Comment: @zerkms - why not just bookmark the 11.2 doc homepage in your favourite browser?

Comment: @user767334 - if you had *read the documentation* that Benoit linked to, you would understand that the 0 is there to provide the leading zero for decimal numbers less than one i.e. what you asked for.

Comment: @user767334 - as for wanting `10` rather than `10.00` that simply doesn't make sense.  All numbers should be displayed in the same format, and in this case that means displaying whole numbers to two decimals.

Answer (score 0):

The LTRIM(TO_CHAR(comm,'999990.99')) works for values which have 2 digits after decimal point.
If value like 0.123523 is used above it rounds off the decimal places keeping 2 digits only.